# Installing h5py on OS X

Tags: python, macos, import, hdf5, h5py

I've spent the day trying to get the `h5py` module of python working, but without success. I've installed HDF5 shared libraries, followed the instructions I could find on the web to get it right. But it doesn't work, below is the error message I get when trying to import the module into python. I tried installing through MacPorts too but again it wouldnt work.

I'm using Python27 32 bits (had too for another module, and thus installed the i386 HDF5 library... if that's right?)

Any help very welcome !

Thank you !

```
import h5py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

      from h5py import _errors

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_errors.so, 2): Symbol not found: _H5E_ALREADYEXISTS_g

  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_errors.so

  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_errors.so
```

Answer (score 10):

Check that you are not inside the h5py installation directory.

Comment: Also, try opening up a new terminal. In linux (which, like OS X, is Unix-like), you can't usually install a python package and then test it in the same terminal.

Comment: Does anyone know why this matters?

Answer (score 0):

My advice, if you can, install h5py using [Anaconda](http:///https://docs.continuum.io/) Distribution Open Data Science Core.